# Link a Local Directory to a Git Initialized Directory so they Sync when Changes are Made to Either One

Tags: linux, git, sync, symbolic-link

Sorry if the question seems ignorant, and sorry for the bad misleading title; I can't describe my problem in one sentence.

I run Arch Linux.

I have a Git repository with my dotfiles (configs). And all of my dotfiles are in `~/.config`, I want to link a directory in `~/.config` to the directory that Git is initialized on which is in `~/.dotfiles`. I've already remotely connected the local repository to GitHub.

I don't want to edit two files every time I want to make a change. I also don't want to initialize git in `~/.config` because I only want to publish the dotfiles of one program and it doesn't really make sense to put all the other +100 directories in a `.gitignore` file.

Configurations in `~/.config` are the ones that make changes to the programs. And the configurations in `~/.dotfiles` are just for show so they can be published to GitHub. I want to be able to edit either one and automatically have the changes synced to the other.

All I want is that when I make a change to one of the directories, the change gets synced to the other directory, so I don't have to overwrite the other directory manually every time I make a change.

I've tried symlinks, but when I link the two directories with the `ln` command and then edit files in one directory, it doesn't apply in the other one.

```bash
sudo ln -sf ~/.dotfiles/.config/awesome ~/.config/awesome
# I've also tried
sudo ln -sf ~/.config/awesome ~/.dotfiles/.config/awesome
```

I know I can edit files in one directory then sync it manually with `mv` to overwrite the other directory with the changes; this will work, but the amount of programs will increase so I will have to manually sync all the programs. I am just looking for a simple way to do it, I also heard about `rsync`, but I think it isn't related to my problem.

**EDIT:**

If this doesn't make sense, just tell me how 'dotfile' repositories work, like how is this [repo](https://gitlab.com/dwt1/dotfiles) is made.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how you were creating the symlinks?

Comment: I think something like this can give answers, he use git flags (--git-dir, --work-home) https://fwuensche.medium.com/how-to-manage-your-dotfiles-with-git-f7aeed8adf8b

I personally just use yadm tool.

Comment: @user1686 Edited the post

Comment: In both cases, did you look with `ls -l` to check whether a symlink was actually created in the correct location?

Comment: @user1686 Yes, I've tried and found symlinks.